# Is this checking is the current directory has this file?

Tags: c#, file, directory

fixed used this instead `return (dir.GetFiles().Select(x => x.Name.Equals("retrieve.sh")).Contains(true));`

Comment: This seems like some that would be very trivial to test yourself.

Comment: It returns a boolean (true/false), if the file exists. It's better to use `Path.Combine(@dir.FullName,"retrieve.sh")` to be compatible with other platforms.

Comment: I'm not sure I get the idea to use path combine Jeroen

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint to inspect the `@dir.FullName`?

Comment: added changes to original question guys to better illustrate my problem

Comment: What does `subDirectories` contain? Like, how do you get the current directory?

Comment: i added the code on top its basically a list of folders and in that list of folders some may be empty or have that file or something else but the ones that have that file I do not want to include in my list.add for example

Comment: What does `root` contain?  :-o

Comment: root is a rootdirectory from where to start iterating

Comment: it just has a list of folders as well

Comment: Your criterea says: if `HasPattern` returns true and subdirectory is NOT empty and the file `"retrieve.sh"` could NOT be found, => then add the directory.

Comment: yea its doing what its supposed to be doing,